# Operation timed out dot net core

Tags: postgresql, .net-core

i am working with Postgresql and connecting it to the Dot net Core project.When i try to run update-database it shows error "the operation timed out".
i dont know why i am getting this
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: `;Database=TLS` Is your database called TLS? It most likely should be `;Database=postgres`

Comment: There another databse TLS as well..i have tried postgres as well but still not working

Comment: i have increased the timeout for EF Core but still same issue

Comment: Post your code as text, not screenshots.